# does $f(n) \neq O(g(n))$ implies $g(n)=O(f(n))$

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Im pretty sure it doesn't, but how can I be sure?

Was thinking by using

$$f(x) = \sin(x) + 2$$ and $$g(x) = \cos(x) + 2$$

Thanks!`

Comment: check this out http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10548/construct-two-functions-f-and-g-satisfying-f-ne-og-g-ne-of

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $\sin(x)+2$ and $\cos(x)+2$, then those functions *are* big-O of each other.

A true counterexample would be, $f(n)=1+n^2\sin(n)^2$ and $g(n)=n$.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Let
$f(n) = 1$
if $n$ is even
and
$n$ if $n$ is odd
and let
$g(n) = 1$
if $n$ is odd
and
$n$ if $n$ is even.

Then
$f(n)/g(n) = n$
if $n$ is odd
and
$f(n)/g(n) = 1/n$
if $n$ is even.